# Implementing commands menu button for a telegram bot using telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

I've been trying to set the list of commands for my telegram bot but it doesn't work, here's what I'm doing:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")
bot.set_my_commands(commands = ['start','go','help'])
bot.set_chat_menu_button(bot.get_me().id, types.MenuButtonCommands(type = 'commands'))
```

can anyone help me to figure it out? Thx anyway.

Comment: I figured it out, the list of commands must be in type "BotCommand" passed to the method "set_my_commands" without any use for the method "set_chat_menu_button".

Answer (score 1):

You have given `bot.get_me().id` which gives user_id of the bot. But it needs the chat_id. So give `message.chat.id`.
And the `bot.set_my_commands()` takes a `list` of `BotCommands`. But you have given an ordinary list.
Try:

```
c1 = types.BotCommand(command='start', description='Start the Bot')
c2 = types.BotCommand(command='help', description='Click for Help')
c3 = types.BotCommand(command='go', description='Something')
bot.set_my_commands([c1,c2,c3])
bot.set_chat_menu_button(message.chat.id, types.MenuButtonCommands('commands'))
```